# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')

Tags: javascript

I am coding an app using react, and I got this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')at calculateIntersectionX. I really have no idea why I am getting this error when there's a legit x part in the limits constant.

```
const limits = [
  { x: 12.3456777, y: -12.3456777 },
  { x: 12.3456777, y: -12.3456777 },
  { x: 12.3456777, y: -12.3456777 },
];
for (var i = 0; i < limits.length; i++) {
  for (var g = 0; g < limits.length; i++) {
    if (limits[i] != limits[g]) {
      let a1 = limits[i];
      let a2 = limits[g];
      calculateIntersectionX(avgfakex1, avgfakex2, a1, a2);
      calculateIntersectionY(avgfakey1, avgfakey2, a1, a2);
    }
  }
}


function calculateIntersectionX(p1, p2, p3, p4) {

  var c2x = p3.x - p4.x; // (x3 - x4)
  var c3x = p1.x - p2.x; // (x1 - x2)
  var c2y = p3.y - p4.y; // (y3 - y4)
  var c3y = p1.y - p2.y; // (y1 - y2)
```

Comment: Is avgfakex1-2 and avgfakey1-2 structured as an x/y dictionary? If so it should work.

Comment: What is `avgfakex1` apart from indeed `undefined`, is there a chance for it to have a property `x`? How about stepping through with a debugger to see what is going on or simply placing a `console.log` into `calculateIntersection`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change:

- Inner loop increases 'i' instead of 'g'.
- consider using only one loop.
- in "if (limits[i] != limits[g])" you checking if object is equal to object maybe you want to check if limits[i].x is equal to limits[g].x.

consider fixing these and maybe it will help you figure it out :)